Does an improper integral converge: $\int_0^{\infty} x^p \exp(-x^q) dx$
Does
$\int_0^\infty x^p e^{-x^q}dx$ converge where $p,q>0$
I thought about making a substitution, then showing it was bounded (the one I considered was $u=-x^{-q}$) but I wasn’t having any success.

Compute $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2.x^pe^{-x^q}$ and conclude.

Use $x^q=t$ to face a simple problem. Think also about the gamma function.
